# Unable to map the Source report Lookup field with Target object text field in reporting snapshot

Tags: reporting, tasks, activity, snapshot

We have a source report using which we have created a reporting snapshot that will store the data to the target object using the mapping.

However as per the research and finding on google I created the text field in target object to capture the record type from the source report , however it did not worked yet.

Please advise on this.

Thanks

Comment: I think you are referring this article: [Include Record type details in a Reporting Snapshot](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003137&language=en_US&type=1) .Have you followed same steps? This says creating a formula not text field.

Answer (score 1):

As per @Mr.Frodo's suggested [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003137&language=en_US&type=1) you need:

> **As a workaround**, you can create a Text formula for the desired field, add the fields to your
>   report, and then map it in the Reporting Snapshot.

From what you said in your question it seems that you did one half of the job - created a Text field on the Target object which is still not enough to achieve what you want.